# Regex pattern to match directories with a prefix

Tags: regex, git, pre-commit-hook

I am a bit of regex newbie and I can't figure out how to set up a regular expression for this pattern I am trying to do.

The expression is meant to be in a Python pre-commit script and it will run a pre-commit hook if the files being commits match it.

My example list of files

```
vars/prod-region1/mysql.yml
vars/prod-region1/keys.yml
vars/prod-region1/test.yml
vars/stage-region2/mysql.yml
vars/stage-region2/keys.yml
vars/stage-region2/test.yml
vars/local/mysql.yml
vars/local/test.yml
```

I need a regex pattern that will match files that fall in the following directory pattern

- vars/prod*/mysql.yml
- vars/prod*/keys.yml
- vars/stage*/mysql.yml
- vars/stage*/keys.yml

my effort at the moment is

```
vars/(prod*|stage*)/(mysql|keys).yml
```

which is severely wrong. Any help would be great.

Comment: Fantastic question by the way. Keep it up. As for your expression it is the following: `vars\/(prod|stage).*?\/(mysql|keys)\.yml`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `*` incorrectly. It is a repetition indicator, not a multi-character wildcard; there is no generic (variable length) wildcard in regular expression syntax. There are, however, single-character wildcards and quasi-wildcards. So, for example, `.*` matches any character, zero or more times. `\S*` matches zero or more non-whitespace characters. In your example, however, `d*` matches zero or more `d`s in a row. Similarly with `e*`.

You need to use something to match the additional characters. In this case, you want non-whitespace characters, zero or more times, so you should use `\S*`. You also should escape the `/` characters. And when you mean a literal `.`, not a wildcard character, you need to escape `.`, as well.:

```
vars\/(prod\S*|stage\S*)\/(mysql|keys)\.yml
```

[Here's a **demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dY3lI5/1).

Comment: There we go :) I was just about to say you need to escape `/`. Good luck in the elections, btw.

Comment: @iismathwizard Yep, caught it. :)

Comment: Probably should escape `.` since you actually mean `\.` it just so happens that `.` *technically* covers your ass ;p

Comment: @iismathwizard Indeed. My first version of the post was a little sloppy; cleaning it up now.

Comment: Awesome answer! Exactly what I was looking for and a clear explanation on what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @MechaStorm Glad to help out!